# Riemann Integral Condition and Jordan Measure

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

The below image is an excerpt from Thomas Hawkins’ Lebesgue’s Theory of Integration: Its History and Development.

Following the excerpt, the author says in the next page that (R1) represents the “germs of (Jordan) measurability”. I am trying to understand this.

A set is Jordan measurable whenever the infimum of the sum of the measure of simple sets whose union covers it, equals the supremum of the sum of the measure of simple sets whose union is contained in it.

How does this connect to (R1)?

[image]

Comment: Use the concept of Jordan measure for region between graph of function and x-axis.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thanks for the reply! I am not sure I see the connection still with (R1) - is (R1) telling us that, as the partition norm becomes smaller, the “extra space” included in a particular sum of Jordan measure of simple sets approaches 0 if and only if the region between the graph and the x-axis is Jordan measurable? (Where the particular simple sets are those whose widths are the $\delta_i$, and height are some value of $f$ evaluated in the sub-interval?)

Comment: $R1$ is difference between upper and lower Darboux sums and one can relate it to the difference between measures of rectangles containing the region in my comment and measures of rectangles contained in that region. More formally it says that the graph of function has Jordan measure zero.